# D3 - Respond to interactions between objects

Tags: javascript, events, svg, d3.js

I have a feeling that my main problem is that I just don't know what question to ask. I hope that your suggestions to solve this example problem will point me in the right direction to handle situations like these.

Here's a very simple example I just threw together for the sake of illustration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">

    <div id="viz"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500);
    
    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data([0])
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 250)
        .attr("cy", 250)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "white");

    var m = svg.selectAll("circle.moving")
        .data([0])
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 100)
        .attr("cy", 100)
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", "red");

    repeat();

    function repeat() {
        m.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return Math.floor(Math.random()*450);})
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return Math.floor(Math.random()*450);})
        .each("end", repeat);
    }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: demo]
<sub>(source: [andrewlaprise.com](http://andrewlaprise.com/demo/demo.gif))</sub>

Now let's say I wanted to have something occur every time the red circle collides with the white circle.  What if there were a lot of white circles?  What if there were a dynamic number of white circles whose positions were controlled by the user?

Should I use some kind of event?  I'm new to event-driven programming and I don't have an intuition for it yet.

I suspect the answer to this question will open a lot of doors for me (and at least tell me what I need to google).  How should I best listen for that collision?

Comment: Every time the red circle moves, check whether it intersects with (one of the) white circle(s).

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff, thanks for the tip. It's an obvious answer, but I just assumed I was unaware of some tool. That said, I'm not sure I know how to constantly track the red ball's location during each transition. My understanding is that transition() doesn't have a tick event, so I can't use that.  Seems hacky to poll... Am I missing something obvious?  
To simplify, let's say I wanted to know if at any point during the transition, the red ball's {"cx", "cy"} was the same as the white ball's. How can I track the red ball's location with that level of granularity? Thanks again for your feedback!

Comment: Well in this particular case you know the exact path the red circle will take. Therefore, you can compute whether, at any point, it will intersect something else. If the white circles are user draggable, you can check again in the drag handler.

Comment: Alright, @LarsKotthoff, thanks for the feedback. Everything you're saying is really obvious, but for whatever reason, I just firmly believed that I must have been missing SOMETHING. Guess not! Thanks so much for taking the time to answer that silly, silly question.